# Google Sheets API Python

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Есть функция:

```
def get_cell_range(start, finish):
    """Функция возвращает массив значений заданного диапазона ячеек.
    Значения пустых ячеек в массив не записываются.
    Если соединение с сервером google не установлено возвращает соответствующее
    сообщение"""
    flag = True
    CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'json файл'  
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CREDENTIALS_FILE, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
    httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    try:
        service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http = httpAuth) # пробуем авторизоваться в гугл таблицах
    except Exception as e:
        report =' Сервер google временно недоступен. Повторите попытку позже. Чтобы продолжить введите команду /menu'
        flag = False
        return flag, report
    spreadsheetId = 'ID таблицы'
    
    range_name = '1p!{0}:{1}'
    range_name=range_name.format(start, finish)
    
    table = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=range_name).execute()
    ans_value = table['values']
    res=[]
    for element in ans_value:
        element.append(res[0])
    print(res)
    return flag, res
```

При её выполнении вылазит ошибка:

```
  File "...", line 85, in get_cell_range
    ans_value = table['values']
KeyError: 'values'
```

Не могу понять почему не получается массив значений получить(.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Посмотрите содержимое словаря `table`. Ошибка говорит, что там нет ключа `"values"`.

Comment: в том то и дело, что в словаре table есть ключ value

Comment: `"value"`? Или `"values"`?

Comment: values - точно. у меня есть с этим значением другая функция, она работает. а эта нет

Comment: Проблема нашлась. Я оказывается вывод ключа неправильно прописал. Вот верное написание части функции:       `ans_value = table.get('values',[])
    print (ans_value)
    res=[]
    for element in ans_value:
        element.append(res[0])
    print(res)
    return flag, res`

Comment: Вы можете сами написать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема нашлась. Я оказывается вывод ключа неправильно прописал. Вот верное написание части функции:

```
...
ans_value = table.get('values',[]) 
print (ans_value) 
res=[] 
for element in ans_value: 
    element.append(res[0]) 
print(res) 
return flag, res
```